# How to justify the lightweight symmetric PRESENT encryption algorithm is more secure?

Tags: encryption, symmetric, lightweight

My domain is VLSI design, currently, I'm working on [PRESENT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESENT) Lightweight cryptographic algorithm.

- I want to know how to improve the security of the algorithm rather than increasing bit size?
- Is there any possibility to improve the security of the algorithm by using automatically generated keys rather than manually giving data?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean the block size or the key size? The second question is not clear. As a VLSI designer, why do you need to change the algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to crypto-SE. "secure" is a vague/broad term. Are you interested in improving resistance: (A) to brute force key search? (B) to other cryptanalysis from plaintext/ciphertext pairs? (C) to attacks not on the block cipher, but on encryption mode (e.g. CTR, GCM...) made possible by the 64-bit block size? (D) to key recovery by side-channel attacks (DPA...)? Independently: Are you considering modify anything to the PRESENT cipher itself? If not, are we talking about the 80-bit or 128-bit key variant? Please edit your question, adding that info.

Comment: There are rather good papers out there on the security of PRESENT, and you cannot improve it without creating your own cipher.  The only think that comes to mind might be a key tweak of some sort, but then it's no longer PRESENT.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to forget PRESENT and focus with more attention on [SKINNY](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-53008-5_5) (A lightweight block cipher with acceptable security). The implementation results show that SKINNY is more effective and well suited for resource-constrained environments. Please see its [citetion](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=11642568633099968397) to find more info about its security.

Comment: Your second question sounds like you want to use a KDF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function

Comment: Have you looked on GIFT cipher ?